# Can I build a dll without implementation of a function?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, dll

I would like to build this dll, share it with one who has code that has implementation of this function, and then he/she just links with dll and use it. Is that possible?

I tried it, my Visual Studio gave me an error `LNK2001 unresolved external symbol...`, which indicates that an implementation is mandatory.

Comment: What is the problem that you are trying to solve here?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError There's a large code base that has an implementation of the function I need, but I can't access it because I'm an intern. My colleague wants to use my code in the large code base, I've been asked to provide a dll for him so that he can use it. But my dll can't be built without an implementation of a function.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the structure here. Does your dll provide some function that needs to call this other function you don't have the definition for?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you could have your dll dynamically call another (dummy) dll, which only has empty shell functions for each relevant routine and then later replace the dummy one with the real thing that you get from your co-worker.

Comment: @Kevin I create and provide objects by exported function. The function I don't have definition for is used in member function of these created objects.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError That sounds good, I'll have a try, thanks!